# Ember.js RC3 and JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js

I'm developing a web interface using ember rc 3.0 and I can't integrate with JQuery mobile.

The issue its when i try to render something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    <!-- page : home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Ferramentas</h1> 
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input type="search" name="search-2" id="search-2" value="" placeholder="Pesquisar" />
            </div>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#changePassword" data-transition="slide">Change Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="#messageBox">Message Box </a></li>
                <li><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    {{outlet}}

</script>
```

its keeps in blank.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Versions of Jquery and Jquery Mobile?